# MS Project - task is 365 days, but calendar dates are less

Tags: microsoft-project-2010

I am working on a file in MS Project. I have a task that is auto-scheduled and the duration is 365 days. The start date is 7/5 and the calculated finish date is 5/24 which is obviouslby not correct. I have my calendar set to 7 day working week. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you [edit] and use an international format for those dates?  However I read them, it appears to have more than 365 days, not less.

Comment: If you have created a calendar that sets 7 working days (change to Work Week) and the task starts on July 5, 2015 (Sunday) - 365 days later should be July 3, 2016.

Can you give us year as well as date data?
Do you have resource's assigned with a different working time definition?  In File > Options, Schedule - what is your definition of hours per day?

Answer (score 0):

Create a calendar based on the 24 hr calendar, with the following customisation:

Hours per day: 7.3

Hours per week: 51

Days per month: 100

Duration is entered in: Months

Default task type: Fixed Duration